# "Перемывать кости"

Tags: этимология, фразеология

Откуда пошло выражение "Перемывать кости" и что оно изначально значило?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В старину считалось, что умерший человек, отягощенный множеством грехов, превращается в вампира. И, чтобы не дать этому случиться, через некоторое время покойников выкапывали, а их кости промывали чистой водой.
Теперь выражение имеет значение "сплетничать".

Comment: это в какой культуре такое было принято?

Comment: Во многих, в т.ч. и славянских. Правда акценты расставлены несколько своеобразно. Вампиризм тут ни при чем.

Answer (score 0):

Современная форма фразеологического сращения перемывать косточки, синонимического глаголам сплетничать, злословить, судачить (о ком-либо), сменила более старую перемывать кости, известную еще в XIX веке. Именно эта старая форма и явилась основой для образования слова костить "ругать".

Оборот "перемывать кости" в качестве устойчивого сочетания слов родился на базе переменного словосочетания, связанного с существованием в древности у славян обрядом так называемого вторичного захоронения, которое осуществлялось спустя несколько лет после похорон умершего для очищения его от грехов и снятия с него заклятия. Перед вторичным захоронением выкопанные останки (т. е. кости) перемывались, что, естественно, сопровождалось воспоминаниями о покойнике, оценкой его характера, поступков и дел. Это и явилось причиной образно-метафорического переосмысления слов перемывать кости, первоначально имевших самый прямой, буквальный смысл.

(gramota.ru)

Answer (score 0):

Так это отрицательное выражение говорить за спиной встречается в тексте 5 века,
Коран 49.12 не пересуждайте заочно одни других: захочет ли кто нибудь из вас есть мясо своего умершего брата?
Этот смысл ближе к пересудам и костям.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).